Disable SSH during the installer
I'm installing ubuntu 22.04 using subiquity and autoinstall. While I DO want ssh to be installed in the final system, I do NOT want it to be running while the installer is running, which instead it does.
Is there some kernel/subiquity option to prevent SSH from running during the installation?

You can use the kernel parameter systemd.mask=ssh when booting the installer.
Links

More information about systemd kernel parameters: https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/en/man7/kernel-command-line.7.html
More information about mask: https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/en/man1/systemctl.1.html

